# Transpose or not before finding basis for subspaces V and U

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ is a subspace with basis **a** and **b**. $V$ is a subspace with basis **c** and **d**. All vectors - **a b c d** - are 4x1-vectors. Find a basis for $U+V$.

I think the algorithm here is to put **a b c d** inside a matrix, perform row reduction, see what free variables I get (for example 1 and 3) and then conclude those original vectors are basis (for examle a and c).

However, maybe I need to transpose first?

Comment: Happy with my answer? any clarifications needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you make $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ the rows of a matrix, then after row reduction the nonzero rows will be a basis of $U+V$.

If you make them the columns of a matrix, then after row reduction you find the columns that have a leading 1; the corresponding columns in the original matrix will be a basis for $U+V$.